# Why Does My EditorTemplate Get Executed Even When Property Is Null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I've got a model like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
   public class ChildViewModel { get; set; }
   // other properties
}
```

Then in the view for `ParentViewModel`, i do this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChildViewModel)
```

And it executes my custom editor template, even when `Model.ChildViewModel` is `null`. Why? I thought MVC was smart enough to only render the view/template when it has a value. (e.g the default template for `null` is to not render anything).

Because at the moment, i would have to wrap the HTML in my custom editor template with:

`@if (Model != null)`

Which seems very silly.

Is this a known problem?

I'm on ASP.NET MVC 3, Razor.

Comment: I would assume it is for when you need to create a ChildViewModel object, you can send in a new'd up/empty version of ChildViewModel - put it in an editorFor template, have the user fill it out and then retrieve the values.  If the MVC team were to ignore empty ViewModels on templates, you would need a CreateFor helper as well.  My 2 cents...

Comment: @Tommy - but there's a difference between a `null` object and an `empty` one (e.g instantiated, but all properties null). That's the point - if i wanted the user to fill it out, i would new up the object. I'm explicitly not instantiating because i don't want a template rendered.

Comment: I don't think MVC is that smart.  It expects if you call a render method (displayFor, EditFor, Partial) and send it a model, then that model will have a value (else NullReferenceException).  Either have 2 different views, do you model != null check or do a renderAction method passing a parameter from your primary model that lets that action know if you should return a view or return nothing.

Comment: @Tommy - you could be right. Although if i have a polymorphic model (declared as abstract in ViewModel, implemented two different ways in controller), MVC is smart enough to pick the right derived template. But guess it's not smart enough to handle this scenario. You should add an answer, i'll leave this Q open for another couple of days, and if no-one has anything to the contrary i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Sounds good - I hope someone has some better news too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than testing for null before your partial or inside it you can use a new extension method. This also gives you more options for how to deal with a null model. Here's the extensions I use, it will test for null and either return an empty string or a different partial on a null result. This can be particularly helpful on things like pagers where the page is out of range as you can have a separate partial with your "no results" information.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class nullpartials
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString NullPartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string Partial, object Model)
        {
            if (Model == null)
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            else
                return helper.Partial(Partial, Model);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString NullPartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string Partial, string NullPartial, object Model)
        {
            if (Model == null)
                return helper.Partial(NullPartial);
            else
                return helper.Partial(Partial, Model);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString NullPartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string Partial, object Model, ViewDataDictionary viewdata)
        {
            if (Model == null)
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            else
                return helper.Partial(Partial, Model, viewdata);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString NullPartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string Partial, string NullPartial, object Model, ViewDataDictionary viewdata)
        {
            if (Model == null)
                return helper.Partial(NullPartial, viewdata);
            else
                return helper.Partial(Partial, Model, viewdata);
        }

        public static void RenderNullPartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string Partial, object Model)
        {
            if (Model == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                helper.RenderPartial(Partial, Model);
                return;
            }
        }

        public static void RenderNullPartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string Partial, string NullPartial, object Model)
        {
            if (Model == null)
            {
                helper.RenderPartial(NullPartial);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                helper.RenderPartial(Partial, Model);
                return;
            }
        }

        public static void RenderNullPartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string Partial, object Model, ViewDataDictionary viewdata)
        {
            if (Model == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                helper.RenderPartial(Partial, Model, viewdata);
                return;
            }
        }

        public static void RenderNullPartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string Partial, string NullPartial, object Model, ViewDataDictionary viewdata)
        {
            if (Model == null)
            {
                helper.RenderPartial(NullPartial, viewdata);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                helper.RenderPartial(Partial, Model, viewdata);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Sorry I misready the question being about EditorTemplates. However I see no reason that the same approach can't work for EditorFor, you just have a few more method signatures to replicate.

Comment: Good idea, but this is for a *form*. So if i use partial, i lose the model hierachies when MVC renders out the input elements, whereas `EditorFor` respects those hierachies, e.g `<input type="text" name="Model.Orders[0].Name".>`. Good idea for handling this scenario with partials though, +1.

Comment: @RPM1984 misread the question sorry, updated the answer to just say that the same approach should work for EditorFor aswell

Comment: yep, that would work. I could just extract the model metadata from the lambda expression supplied to `EditorFor`. However, i ended up needing this template rendered via AJAX for another page, so i needed to serve it via a child action. So in the child action, i did the null check. Will accept this though, as it's a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MVC is that smart. It expects if you call a render method (displayFor, EditFor, Partial) and send it a model, then that model will have a value (else NullReferenceException). Your choices as far as I know are:

1. Either have 2 different views (perhaps 2 different view models?)
2. Do you model != null check
3. Use a renderAction method passing a parameter from your primary model that lets that action know if you should return a view/partial view or return nothing.

Comment: ended up going with 3. I didn't pass a parameter, but instead did `return model == null ? null : PartialView(model)` in the child action. Accepted @Chao's answer because it's the most simple/re-usable solution if people were to stumble across this question. +1 for your help.